# root access from script

Tags: passwords

Is there a way to gain root access without user input?

I want a script automatically looks at a stored password, then authenticates with that password. Is there a way to do this without user input? I tried `man su` and `man sudo`, but these don't support this. Is this possible?

P.S: I know python, sh and bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link. It explains how to do this in python. [Root Access Python](http://forums.devshed.com/linux-help-33/run-script-as-root-without-typing-root-password-43815.html)

The basic of it is changing the permission of the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - Use cron**

If the script is a cron job, it can be kicked off by root's crontab.  Then it is automatically running as root.  Be REALLY careful though as you are running as root.  Anyone who can change your script has just become root.

**Option 2 - Set up a new id**

If the task can be done by a non-root user, you don't actually need root each time.